# Error when create a directive with Kendo Ui treeview, object of my treeView is undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, kendo-ui

Same problem here : [How to access and read Kendo TreeView in AngularJS controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276348/how-to-access-and-read-kendo-treeview-in-angularjs-controller)
I tried to create a directive in Angular 1.4.7 using kendo UI treeview Angular JS (https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dialog/treeview-integration-angularjs), defined in the template of my directive.

This is the code of my directive:

```
angular
  .module('app.criteres.multifiches')
  .directive('mydirective', ['commonServices', '$rootScope', defineDirective]);

  function defineDirective($common, $rootScope) {
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        templateUrl: '../Scripts/Templates/formSelection.html',
        restrict: 'EA',
        controller: ControllerFichesStructurees
    };

   function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    var data = [{ "EmployeeId": 1, "FullName": "Nancy Davolio", "HasEmployees": false, "ReportsTo": 2 }, { "EmployeeId": 3, "FullName": "Janet Leverling", "HasEmployees": false, "ReportsTo": 2 }, { "EmployeeId": 4, "FullName": "Margaret Peacock", "HasEmployees": false, "ReportsTo": 2 }, { "EmployeeId": 5, "FullName": "Steven Buchanan", "HasEmployees": true, "ReportsTo": 2 }, { "EmployeeId": 8, "FullName": "Laura Callahan", "HasEmployees": false, "ReportsTo": 2 }];
    scope.treeViewOptions = {
            dataSource: data,
            dataTextField: "FullName",
            checkboxes: true,
            loadOnDemand: false,
            expandAll: true,
            dataBound: function (e) {
                e.sender.expand(e.node);
            },
            check: function (e) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.selectedEmployeesCount = getCheckedItems(e.sender).length;
                    });
                })
            }
        }

    function ControllerFichesStructurees($scope) {
        $scope.dialogShow = function () {
            angular.element(document.getElementById("employeesSearch")).focus();
            var dataSource = $scope.treeView.dataSource;
            $scope.treeView.element.find(".k-checkbox").removeAttr("checked").trigger("change");
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.repeaterItems.length; i++) {
                var item = $scope.treeView.findByText($scope.repeaterItems[i]["FullName"]);
                item.find(".k-checkbox").first().click();
            }
        }
```

and in "formSelection.html" I have:

```
<div kendo-tree-view="treeView" k-options="treeViewOptions"></div>
```

And a button to test:

```
<button kendo-button class="k-primary" ng-click="dialogShow()">TEST</button>
```

Finally in my main html page "index.html" I have:

```
<mydirective></mydirective>
```

When I click on the button "TEST", I get an error on the line "var dataSource = $scope.treeView.dataSource;" (angular-js:462 TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataSource' of undefined). I checked in the different scopes and the variable $treeView is not present.

Note: the directive's controller is contained in another $scope before $rootscope, could there be an issue?